# c++ i cant understand the difference between const char* and char*

Tags: c++, char, constants

I know you will say its a duplpicate but belive me i read alot of articles about this but i still cant understand what is the diffrence so im giving two examples.
1.

```
int strlen(const char* string)
{
   int i = 0;
   while (string[i] != '\0')
   {
       ++i;
   }
   return i;
}
```

2.

```
int strlen(char* string)
{
   int i = 0;
   while (string[i] != '\0')
   {
       ++i;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Main:

```
int main() 
{
    char str[] = "Hello";
    cout << strlen(str) << endl;
}
```

The second will work and wont get errors while the first wont.

Comment: What error do you get on the first one?

Comment: Consider also `char *const`, which is different from other ones.

Comment: The first should work just fine.

Comment: Unless he's included `<string.h>`, in which case, it's ambiguous with the standard library function.

Comment: The first one [works just fine](http://ideone.com/nlkB00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: you can **not** change value of `string`, it's read-only. It's used to prevent function from changing value of parameter (*Principle of least privilege*)

Case 2: you can change value of `string`.

Also, check that link from comments.

Comment: No, not correct. You can change the value of `string` in either function. In the first, you cannot change the value of `string[N]` for any given `N`.

Comment: That's correct, you can change value of pointer. What I said is `const char * const`